# How to get original codes from generated pattern in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, pattern-matching, messageformat

Suppose I have `java.util.Set<String>` of `"200Y2Z", "20012Y", "200829", "200T2K"` which follows the same pattern `"200$2$"`, where `"$"` is the placeholder. Now which is the most efficient way to get Set of just unique codes from such strings in Java?

Input: `java.util.Set<String>` of `"200Y2Z", "20012Y", "200829", "200T2K"`

Expected output: `java.util.Set<String>` of `"YZ", "1Y", "89", "TK"`

My Try ::

```
public static void getOutPut()
    {
        Set<String> input = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> output = new HashSet<String>();
        StringBuffer out = null;
        for(String in : input)
        {
            out = new StringBuffer();
            StringCharacterIterator sci = new StringCharacterIterator(in);
            while (sci.current( ) != StringCharacterIterator.DONE){
                if (sci.current( ) == '$')
                {
                    out.append(in.charAt(sci.getIndex()));
                }
                sci.next( );
            }
            output.add(out.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

It is working fine, but is there any efficient way than this to achieve it? I need to do it for more than 1000K codes.

Comment: Why dont use substring to get the 3th and last index and to concatenate them into String?

Comment: Hi @drgPP, thanks for your quick response but pattern is dynamic.

Comment: use charAt method and then concatenate them.

Comment: Any code from your side?

Comment: Hi @downvotter can you explain, why???

Answer (score 1):

Get the indexes of the placeholder in the pattern:

```
int i = pattern.getIndexOf('$');
```

You'll must to iterate to obtain all the indexes:

```
pattern.getIndexOf('$', lastIndex+1);
```

The loop and the checks are up to you.

Then use `charAt` with the indexes over each element of the set.